# Should a NSObject model be passed in and out of a controller method or can it be mutated in place?

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm using an NSObject derived model to track data about an individual person in a facial recognition app.

The flow of my app is depicted below. After the model is created, each method performs some image processing and assigns the result to the model that was passed in. Then passes the model back out.

```
CVPersonModel * newPerson = [[CVPersonModel alloc] initWithImage:img];

newPerson = [self.faceProcessor processFaceFromImage:preProcessedImg withModel:newPerson];

newPerson = [self.eyeProcessor processEyesFromImage:processFaceFromImage:preProcessedImg withModel:newPerson];

newPerson = [self.lipsProcessor processLipsFromImage:preProcessedImg withModel:newPerson];
```

The problem is i'm running into some memory leaks related to this model, and I wonder if part of it may be re-assigning it multiple times across multiple threads?

Would it be better (and is it possible) to mutate the object in place?

The calls above would be the same, except each method returns void. Because the model is actually a pointer, newPerson in the calling method should reflect all changes made within each subsidiary method right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make those process methods part of CVPersonModel and call them on the object itself? If you setting the instance of that object with a mutated instance of that same object, best to just use a mutator method.

So it would go like this:

```
[newPerson processFaceWithImage:preProcessedImg];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Right now Each feature processor is a cascade classifier and requires loading a file from disk.  So I have one `PersonProcessor` class that owns each `FeatureProcessor` and applies them to the models as they are passed in. (this class is where the above excerpt is from)

If the models owned the `FeatureProcessor` I thought it might be too much overhead to create a new processor for each model.

Each processor is based on `FeatureProcessor` (~600 lines +~300 lines per subclass) . It just seemed like it would be too much to put all of that in the model class.

Comment: Sorry for the edit  I hit enter and posted by mistake before I was done typing, and then I took to long to edit it so it wouldn't let me apply the edits, thats why I deleted it .

I am in now way opposed to your suggestions, I just wanted to explain why I didn't do this at first and see what your thoughts are?

Comment: Thats ok! The way I see it is that those blocks of 600 lines is going to be run anyways every time you call it, whether it's a method of CVPersonModel or not. So the overhead wouldn't change, just every instance of "newPerson" in the code block for `Feature Processor` would be replaced with `self`. My reasoning is that this is how mutator methods work and setting `newPerson` with a mutated instance of the previous one seemed a little confusing.